# Is there an open source PostgreSQL IDE that allows for model generation?

Tags: postgresql, erd

I have done quite a lot of SQL Server work where I could use SSMS. Now I'm working with Postgres and I miss the ability to generate models (diagrams) from existing relations (taking into account relationships).

I really like pgAdmin, but it looks like the designer is separate (pgDesigner) and old. I really like Navicat's designer, but it's quite expensive.

What are the best options for postgres ER models that are open source/free?

Comment: pgDesigner is not "old - it is actively maintained, but you have to compile it yourself (or donate to get a pre-built binary)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. I did not know that it was still actively maintained. Ideally I would like the designer and db navigator to be the same IDE. Just like SSMS :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found only one.

```
https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler
```

It's free, but nobody's stopping you from donating.

Comment: Thanks - happy to donate to software I use (and I do). i try to avoid spending $1200 though, which is what an all encompassing license for navicat costs!

Comment: If you try it, let us know how it went.